# KSQL Array Of Object

Tags: ksqldb

I'm trying to fetch data from Object Array with ksql Any one Can Helps Me :)

i have JSON Message

```
"Total": [
        {
          "TotalType": "Standard",
          "TotalAmount": 15.99
        }
```

i write this but it dosn't work

```
create stream test2 (Total Array<STRUCT>< <TotalAmount Double>) with(KAFKA_TOPIC='hermes__output',VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

```
create stream test2 (Total[0] STRUCT<TotalAmount Double>) with(KAFKA_TOPIC='hermes__output',VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

thx

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the actual JSON message that you're working with please?

Comment: done 
the solution is here : https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/nested-json-data

Comment: @Wahib: You should add an "Answer" to this question, summarize your solution (including the hyperlink), and then mark your Answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
create stream test2 
   (Total Array<STRUCT< TotalType STRING, TotalAmount Double >>) 
   with(KAFKA_TOPIC='hermes__output',VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```